# What is the default “tag” function for template literals?

Tags: javascript, templates

### What is the name of the native function that handles template literals?

That is, I know that when you write `` tag`Foo ${'bar'}.`; ``, that’s just syntactic sugar for `tag(['Foo ', '.'], 'bar');`.¹

But what about just `` ​`Foo ${'bar'}.`; ``? I can’t just “call” `(['Foo ', '.'], 'bar');`. If I already have arguments in that form, what function should I pass them to?

**I am only interested in the native function that implements the template literal functionality.** I am quite capable of rolling my own, but the purpose of this question is to avoid that and do it “properly”—even if my implementation is a perfect match of current native functionality, the native functionality can change and I want my usage to still match. So answers to this question should take on one of the following forms:

1. The name of the native function to use, ideally with links to and/or quotes from documentation of it.
2. Links to and/or quotes from the spec that defines precisely what the implementation of this function is, so that if I roll my own at least I can be sure it’s up to the (current) specifications.
3. A backed-up statement that the native implementation is unavailable and unspecified. Ideally this is backed up by, again, links to and/or quotes from documentation, but if that’s unavailable, I’ll accept other sources or argumentation that backs this claim up.

---

1. <sub>Actually, the first argument needs a `raw` property, since it’s a `TemplateStringsArray` rather than a regular array, but I’m skipping that here for the sake of making the example more readable.</sub>

---

#### Motivation

I am trying to create a tag function (`tag`, say) that, internally, performs the default template literal concatenation on the input. That is, I am taking the `TemplateStringsArray` and the remaining arguments, and turning them into a single string that has already had its templating sorted out. (This is for passing the result into another tag function, `otherTag` perhaps, where I want the second function to treat everything as a single string literal rather than a broken up template.)

For example, `` tag`Something ${'cooked'}.`; `` would be equivalent to `` otherTag`Something cooked.`; ``.

#### My current approach

The definition of `tag` would look something like this:

```js
function tag(textParts, ...expressions) {
  const cooked = // an array with a single string value
  const raw = // an array with a single string value
  return otherTag({ ...cooked, raw });
}
```

Defining the value of `raw` is fairly straightforward: I know that `String.raw` is the tag function I need to call here, so `const raw = [String.raw(textParts.raw, ...expressions)];`.

But I cannot find anywhere on the internet what function I would call for the `cooked` part of it. What I want is, if I have `` tag`Something ${'cooked'}.`; ``, I want `` const cooked = `Something ${cooked}.`; `` in my function. But I can’t find the name of whatever function accomplishes that.

The closest I’ve found was a claim that it could be implemented as

```js
const cooked = [expressions.map((exp, i) => textParts[i] + exp).join('')];
```

This is wrong—`textParts` may be longer than `expressions`, since `` tag`Something ${'cooked'}.`; `` gets `['Something ', '.']` and `['cooked']` as its arguments.

Improving this expression to handle that isn’t a problem:

```js
const cooked = [
  textParts
    .map((text, i) => (i > 0 ? expressions[i-1] : '') + text)
    .join(''),
];
```

But that’s not the point—I don’t want to roll my own here and risk it being inconsistent with the native implementation, particularly if that changes.

Comment: There isn't a default one, unfortunately. You'll have to make your own. Occasionally I've used [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) as `unindent = (...args) => String.raw(...args).replaceAll(/^\s+/g, "")` for example. It works for minor-ish stuff when you just want the template processed and then post-process it yourself but it will transform some symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The name of the native function to use, ideally with links to and/or quotes from documentation of it.

There isn't one. It is syntax, not a function.

> Links to and/or quotes from the spec that defines precisely what the implementation of this function is, so that if I roll my own at least I can be sure it’s up to the (current) specifications.

Section [13.2.8 Template Literals](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-template-literals) of the specification explains how to process the syntax.

Comment: 1) Applying a tag to a string template is a syntax, but the tag itself is just a function; the signature of the built-in `String.raw(…)` allows it to be used as a tag. 2) A reference to a spec is not a good answer, – otherwise, virtually all SO questions can be answered with just a link to the spec. The answer should be either a reference to a specific function in standard library (e.g., an MDN link), or an implementation of a custom one (assuming that one can exist).